# Spark broadcast error: exceeds spark.akka.frameSize Consider using broadcast

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a large data called "edges"

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[(String, Int)]] = MappedRDD[27] at map at <console>:52
```

When I was working in standalone mode, I was able to collect, count and save this file.  Now, on a cluster, I'm getting this error

```
edges.count
...
Serialized task 28:0 was 12519797 bytes which exceeds spark.akka.frameSize
  (10485760 bytes). Consider using broadcast variables for large values.
```

Same with .saveAsTextFile("edges")

This is from the spark-shell.  I have tried using the option
    --driver-java-options "-Dspark.akka.frameSize=15"

But when I do that, it just hangs indefinitely. Any help would be appreciated.

** EDIT **

My standalone mode was on Spark 1.1.0 and my cluster is Spark 1.0.1.

Also, the hanging occurs when I go to count, collect or saveAs* the RDD, but defining it or doing filters on it work just fine.

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?  If you upgrade to Spark 1.1.0+, this should no longer be an issue since newer versions of Spark automatically broadcast tasks' code.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I will try that and let you know.  I'm on 1.0.1 right now.

Comment: Also, do you have any workarounds for 1.0.1 until I upgrade?

Comment: I posted an answer just to provide some additional context for the error message and pointers to relevant JIRAs.  There was definitely a bug in Spark 1.0.0 related to larger frame sizes (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1112), but it should have been fixed by 1.0.1.  When you say that it hangs, at what point does it hang?  When launching the shell?  Running a job?  Launching executors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "Consider using broadcast variables for large values" error message usually indicates that you've captured some large variables in function closures.  For example, you might have written something like

```
val someBigObject = ...
rdd.mapPartitions { x => doSomething(someBigObject, x) }.count()
```

which causes `someBigObject` to be captured and serialized with your task.  If you're doing something like that, you can use a [broadcast variable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.1/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) instead, which will cause only a reference to the object to be stored in the task itself, while the actual object data will be sent separately.

In Spark 1.1.0+, it isn't strictly necessary to use broadcast variables for this, since tasks will automatically be broadcast (see [SPARK-2521](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2521) for more details).  There are still reasons to use broadcast variables (such as sharing a big object across multiple actions / jobs), but you won't *need* to use it to avoid frame size errors.

Another option is to increase the Akka frame size.  In any Spark version, you should be able to set the `spark.akka.frameSize` setting in `SparkConf` prior to creating your SparkContext.  As you may have noticed, though, this is a little harder in `spark-shell`, where the context is created for you.  In newer versions of Spark (1.1.0 and higher), you can pass `--conf spark.akka.frameSize=16` when launching `spark-shell`.  In Spark 1.0.1 or 1.0.2, you should be able to pass `--driver-java-options "-Dspark.akka.frameSize=16"` instead.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head.  I have a large object mapped from a text file. If I increase the frameSize, it will hang when I go to count or .saveAsTextFile.  Everything previous works just fine.  Any suggestions on how to tackle the hanging?  Thanks!

Comment: Ultimately, I upgraded to 1.1.0.  But as i was still building a large dataset, i had to send in --executor-memory 16g