# How to solve "job aborted due to stage failure" from "spark.akka.framesize"?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark program which is doing a bunch of column operations, and then calling `.collect()` to pull the results into memory.

I am receiving this problem when running the code:

```
An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.

: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Serialized task 302987:27 was 139041896 bytes, which exceeds max allowed: spark.akka.frameSize (134217728 bytes) - reserved (204800 bytes). Consider increasing spark.akka.frameSize or using broadcast variables for large values.
```

The more full stack trace can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/tuP2cPPe

Now I'm wondering what I need to change to my code and/or configuration to solve this.  I have a few ideas:

- Increase the `spark.akka.frameSize`, as suggested.  I am a bit reluctant to do this because I do not know this parameter very well, and for other jobs I might prefer the default.  Is there a way to specify this within an application?  And can it be changed dynamically on the fly within the code similar to number of partitions?
- Decrease the number of partitions before calling `collect()` on the table.  I have a feeling that calling `collect()` when there are too many partitions is causing this to fail.  It is putting too much stress on the driver when pulling all of these pieces into memory.

I do not understand the suggestion `Consider...using broadcast variables for large values`.  How will this help?  I still need to pull the results back to the driver whether I have a copy of the data on each executor or not.

Are there other ideas that I am missing?  Thx.

Comment: Furthermore, what does it mean....`for large values`?  For large values of what?  Large tables?  Large integers?

Comment: Check out this post. It covers a lot of your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218472/spark-broadcast-error-exceeds-spark-akka-framesize-consider-using-broadcast

Answer (score 0):

I think that error is a little misleading.  The error is because the result you are trying to download back to your driver is larger than Akka (the underlying networking library used by spark) can fit in a message.  **Broadcast variables** are used to efficiently **SEND** data to the worker nodes, which is the opposite direction as what you are trying to do.

Usually you don't want to do a collect when it is going to pull back a lot of data because you will lose any parallelism for the job by trying to download that result to one node.  If you have too much data this could either take forever or potentially cause your job to fail.  You can try increasing the Akka frame size until it is large enough that your job doesn't fail, but that will probably just break again in the future when your data grows.

A better solution would be to save the the result to some distributed filesystem (HDFS, S3) using the RDD write APIs.  Then you could either perform more distributed operations with it in follow on jobs using Spark to read it back in, or you could just download the result directly from the distributed file system and do whatever you want with it.