# MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint output in Spark is slowing my jobs. What does it mean?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am getting this output in my spark jobs, and it is adding a lot of latency to my jobs. Just yesterday, I left the job running at this message overnight, and came home to see that nothing more has processed.

```
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMaster: Size of output statuses for shuffle 0 is 930564 bytes
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.47:37232
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.44:55904
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.38:35491
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.43:60071
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.48:39267
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.39:44310
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.42:51390
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.32:36981
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.30:39261
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.34:58811
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.31:39829
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.40:45521
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.46:35892
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.33:35119
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.36:44486
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.37:35971
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.35:59625
16/01/08 18:51:36 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to 172.31.1.45:40861
```

I tried googling it, but documentation was sparse and I could not really understand. Does any one know?

Comment: This might help. The first answer in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904619/apache-spark-message-understanding

Comment: In my case this logging was when I saving the DataFrame to the disk.

Comment: In our case the huge number of files in shuffle storage was culprit.